# How to redirect after login?

Tags: jsf, redirect, managed-bean

I've username and password bound to the backing managed bean.
In the backing bean, when I check the username and password with DB, I want to redirect the page from `login.xhtml` to `home.xhtml`. How can I do that?

Comment: are you using jsf 2 or jsf 1.x ?

Comment: @Daniel: based on his question history, JSF 2.0.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just return the view ID appended with `faces-redirect=true` parameter.

E.g.

```
public String login() {
    User found = userService.find(username, password);

    if (found != null) {
        this.user = found;
        return "home?faces-redirect=true"; // Will redirect to home.xhtml.
    }
    else {
        addGlobalErrorMessage("Unknown login, please try again");
        return null; // Will stay in current view (and show error message).
    }
}
```

Comment: And then ? 
I mean, where do i use that returned string ?
I've a login.xhtml page with say login.java bean binded with it. With this method how do I redirect the user to a whole new page ?

Comment: What have you tried? How doesn't it work for you? You don't need to do anything else. The new page should appear if the view ID is right. The above answer assumes that it's `home.xhtml` which is in the same folder as `login.xhtml`.

Comment: OK, got it. Now can you please tell me how this works ? the faces-redirect is a reserved parameter, right ? and also tell me its working.

Comment: The default `NavigationHandler` implementation handles the navigation. JSF is open source, just check its source. It's all clearly specified in [JSF specification](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr314/index.html). It explicitly mentions the support for `faces-redirect` as well.